# Resending refreshed data to modal view (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, delegates, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a Main ViewController that triggers a Modal ViewController. When this happens, I pass data that was retrieved in the Main ViewController to the Modal ViewController through a segue. That all works as it should.

But inside of that modal view, I have the ability to alter the origin database (like adding a vote / adding a view / etc.)

Now, I have the data from the Main View underneath updating using a delegate function but my question is: How do I resend that new refreshed data to the open modal view if I cannot re-segue?

Do I need to make that data a global struct of some sort and then use NSNotificationCenter to trigger a variable and table update? Or is there a more elegant way? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - I used 2 different delegate functions that called each other's views. Here is the complete logic (without full code for brevity):

1. Main View **segues** to Modal View and passes data to define `var data` found in Modal View
2. User interacts and changes values in Modal View (example: adds votes / adds views), which ultimately alters rankings in external database.

*I only wanted to refresh the source data once and have it cascade down into the modal views*, so:

3. Modal View calls **delegate function** named `func refreshData` found in Main View
4. `func refreshData` function in Main View refreshes originally passed data and then collects it in `var newData`
5. `func refreshData` function in Main View sends `var newData` back to **delegate function** in Modal View named `func successUpdate`
6. `func successUpdate` function in Modal View assigns new value to original variable passed through segue